# Firebase auth (email and password) not authenticating

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm not able to get the firebase auth working. User auth is enabled in the DB and login ID has been created. When is use the debug console of the browser, there is only 1 warning:

```
It looks like you're using the development build of the Firebase JS SDK.
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import the individual SDK components you intend to use.
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
function login(){

    const userEmail = document.getElementById('userEmail');
    const userPassword = document.getElementById('userPassword');
    const loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn');

    loginBtn.addEvenListener('click'), e => {
      const email = userEmail.value;
      const pass = userPassword.value;
}
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
          alert('Wrong password.');
        } else {
          alert(errorMessage);
        }
        console.log(error);
    });
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
            window.location = 'secondpage.html';
          }
        });
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<h1>TESTING</h1>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="author" content="Name"
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="login_div" class="main-div">
<h3>Welcome</h3>
<input id="userEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email..." />
<input id="userPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password..." />

<button click="login()">Login to Account</button>
</div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
   <script>
  // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
    apiKey: "KEY",
    authDomain: "name.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://name.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "testlist",
    storageBucket: "testlist.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "111111111111"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code!

the issue with with your button.

```
<button click="login()">Login to Account</button>
```

`click` is not a valid event, `onclick` is valid.
so your button will look like this:

```
<button onclick="login()">Login to Account</button>
```

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<h1>TESTING</h1>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="author" content="Name"
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="login_div" class="main-div">
<h3>Welcome</h3>
<input id="userEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email..." />
<input id="userPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password..." />

<button onclick="login()">Login to Account</button>
</div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
   <script>
//   Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
    apiKey: "KEY",
    authDomain: "name.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://name.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "testlist",
    storageBucket: "testlist.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "111111111111"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>

<_TEST.js-> 


function login() {
  const userEmail = document.getElementById("userEmail");
  const userPassword = document.getElementById("userPassword");

  const email = userEmail.value;
  console.log("TCL: login -> email", email);
  const pass = userPassword.value;
  console.log("TCL: login -> pass", pass);

  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
    .catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      if (errorCode === "auth/wrong-password") {
        alert("Wrong password.");
      } else {
        alert(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);
    });
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    console.log("TCL: login -> user", user);
    if (user) {
       window.location = "secondpage.html";
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong script.
You are using:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

But you need to use:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.11.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
```

It's been pointed out in many forums that the /firebase one gives this error since you need the /firebase-app one. Just getting the firebase one is probably importing way more then you actually need and it is bloating your app size

Also for your authentication you probably also need:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.11.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.11.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

Comment: regarding the first script (....firebase.js); thats the one i copied from Firebase after the DB was created...i still went ahead and change it, just in case. Also, after adding the other 2 scripts for the AUTH and DB part, im getting a message in the debug console (firebase error ! unexpected token '<'), could it be that i put them in the wrong place? they are in the test.js line 12 and 13 (before signInWithEmailAndPassword). thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @Eddie Can you try putting them as the first thing after <body> of your html file instead of in your test.js file?

Comment: i moved the scripts to the HTML file but the ...firebase-app.js needs to load before anything. So i moved them under : firebase.initializeApp(config); </script>.      I get no errors there (Thank you!!)

Comment: @Eddie no problem glad I could help a bit